# Not Able To Create New Categories In Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

While creating new category in magento 2, I am getting below error:

```
The "Is New" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again.
```

I am using Debian Linux in GCP to host my application.

Please guide me how to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by changing the broken value in `eav_attributes` table.

```
is_new
```

1. mark "is required" to: 0
2. under "default value" text, uncheck the check box and set (write in) the field box: 0

After that ran below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you created attribute in category EAV with required => true.

If added new attribute then plase add field in **category_form.xml**